# Custom Intellij plugin not working in older version from the version its created on

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have created a Intellij idea plugin with java and gradle by using intelli idea 2020.2.2 and its working fine in intellij 2020.2.2 and its higher version but while i am trying  to use it in older versions like 2020.1.X or other older version its not working show "Incompatible with this installation" issue.

I want to use this custom plugin also with older verion.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SpbW.png)

Comment: What compatibility range is configured in your plugin?

Comment: 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version '0.5.0'
intellij {
    version '2020.2.1'
}
and gradle 5.6.4 with jdk 8

Comment: Please check related discussion: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003338799-Build-compatible-plugin